# How to calculate pagerank of subgraph with neo4j algo.pageRank

Tags: networking, neo4j, cypher

The entire graph contains 100 millions nodes and 100 millions edges.
Firstly, I want to get a subgraph of the entire graph, such as subgraph consists of a given node and its neighbors.
Secondly, I want to calculate pagerank or orthers graph algorithm of the subgraph.
Could anyone help me?